# Control AudioUnits from the command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, audio, core-audio, audiounit

Is there any software for the make which offers command line (or other scripting) utility to modify AudioUnit parameters?

The use case is this:

1. Default (Built-In) input
2. Attach better Gain Control
   AudioUnit (the default OS-X gain
   control is inadequate)
3. Attach L-R balance control (or
   "pan")
4. Pass-through (link) to Default
   Output a.k.a. LineIn.app
5. Script control of AudioUnit 2).
   For a 0-100% volume control of the
   input audio. In 1/16 increments
   (6.5%) just like the main volume in
   OS-X.
6. Script control of AudioUnit 3)
   for L-R balance (pan) control.

The problem here for me is at steps 5 and 6.

Steps 1) through to 4) can be adequately achieved graphically in AudioHijackPro. The pass-through, and audio units can be created in there. It also comes with a really good gain control dial / knob. However all those effects are set exclusively through the GUI interface.

Desperately searching for a command-line tool (or "audiounit host") which can set the parameters values and send them to these audio units with the set parameter C api function(s).

Do any existing tools on the Mac offer this kind of functionality?

Comment: This isn't appropriate for Stack Overflow.  Post it on SuperUser.com instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Audio Units need a host to do any audio processing.  What AU host are you trying to control?

Comment: I imagine that what i am looking for in this instance is that the AU host is a commercial software package eg Logic, ProTool etc. And that the App also comes with its own accompanying command line tool. So the command line tool would be controlling the AU host of the GUI app it comes with (eg Logic.app, ProTools.app bundle). As an ALTERNATIVE control mechanism to the usual GUI graphical knobs, dials, whatever. Are there any commercial audio software actually like this?

Comment: should probably be on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want [Triumph](http://www.audiofile-engineering.com/triumph/).  It can't be controlled from the command line but it is Applescript-able.

Answer (score 0):

Spotify's Pedalbord is a Python library that can apply AU plugins:

https://github.com/spotify/pedalboard

With Fire, it's trivial to turn any Python script into a CLI tool:

https://github.com/google/python-fire